# Python: How to scrape contents of list tag inside the head tag with specific text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror, nonetype

## import requests and BeautifulSoup

I want to scrape the "Objectives" part, but there is an error like below.

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'**

Also, I want to make csv table for each lesson.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://studio.code.org/s/web-development-2023/lessons/1"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
element = soup.find(text="Students will be able to:")
text = element.next_sibling.get_text()

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The text you see in the web-page is encoded in Json form in an attribute of `<script>` element (so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it). To get the objectives you can do:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://studio.code.org/s/web-development-2023/lessons/1"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.select_one("[data-lesson]")["data-lesson"])

for o in data["objectives"]:
    print(o["description"])
```

Prints

```
Create a prototype of a web design to meet the needs of a user using the problem-solving process
Identify features of a web design that match the needs of users
Understand the steps of the problem-solving process
```